# Stop an element with relative position affecting the position of other elements

Tags: html, css

I have an element (div2) which I want to position to be just below div1, which I wanted to do using `position:relative`.

When I use `position:relative`, div2 obviously affects the position of div1 and div3, however I would like div2 to not affect their positions, i.e. the positions of div1 and div3 should be the same with div2 removed or with div2 included in the code.

This can be achieved with `position: absolute`, since it brings the element out of the document flow, but then I lose the relative positioning which I feel I need (or would make it easier) to lower div2 to just below div1.

```css
#middle-row{
  margin-top: 25px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around; }

.block {
  height: 100%;
  width: 10vw;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  color: black }

.block span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 85%;
  width: max-content; }

.block .block-input {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative; }
```

```html
<div id="middle-row">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="block"><span>Div1</span></div>
    <div class="block block-input"><span>Div2</span></div> 
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="block"><span>Div3</span></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: BTW, an elemnt cannot be positioned `relative` to *other elements*, it can only be positioned relative to itself.

Comment: Hey! can you maybe explain your problem a bit more by using screenshots or examples? Thank you :P

Comment: Sorry about that, the question was pretty vague. I've rephrased my question and corrected it to include my code

Answer (score 0):

CSS-Grid can do that with some help from flexbox.

```css
#middle-row {
  margin-top: 25px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: space-around;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 10vw;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.block {
  height:10vw;
  width: 10vw;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  color: black
}

.block span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 85%;
  width: max-content;
  color:white;
}

.block .block-input {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="middle-row">
  <a href="#" class="col">
    <div class="block"><span>Div1</span></div>
    <div class="block block-input"><span>Div2</span></div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="block"><span>Div3</span></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check if childrens element have any position absolute